# Wordpress TinyMCE Strips OnClick & OnChange (need jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Searched a long time to find a solution, but can't find one specific to my needs, so apologies if I've missed something.

On my Wordpress site I have a page with a button, which in order to follow the link of that button a checkbox needs to be checked. This is the code for it...

```
<form action="#"><input onchange="toggleAccept()" id="agreeCheckbox" type="checkbox" /><label for="agreeCheckbox">I agree to the terms</label></form>

<a href="link/?cbur=a" id="accept" onclick="mustAccept(); return false;"><img src="button.png"/></a>
```

There's also some code handling this in the head:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function toggleAccept() {
var acceptLink = document.getElementById("accept");
var agreeCheckbox = document.getElementById("agreeCheckbox");
if (agreeCheckbox.checked) {
acceptLink.onclick=function() {
window.location=this.href + "&cbrblaccpt=true";
return false;
}
} else {
acceptLink.onclick=function() {
mustAccept();
return false;
}
}
}
function mustAccept() {
window.alert("Please check the box and agree to the payment terms of this recurring product.");
}

cbrblaccpt
  </script>
```

Basically, if someone tries to click the bottom without checking the box, the above popup appears. Once they check the box, they are taken to the button's link.

The issue I'm having is the TinyMCE is removing the "onchange" and "onclick" parts of the code. I'm guessing because it doesn't like inline Java being there.

After a lot of looking around it seems to me that the ideal solution is to handle this with jQuery in a separate file, but I have absolutely no idea how to do that.

If someone could help in that regard, or perhaps offer another work around then I'm all ears.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Well... yes you can handle it with pure jQuery.

I've made an example for you:

REMEMBER to add the jQuery library to your document, just before this `<script>` and if possible, just before `</body>` closing HTML tag :D

**jQuery**:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var agree = $("#accept"); //we cache the element, dont worry

    $("#agreeCheckbox").click(function () {
        var checked_status = this.checked;
        if (checked_status === true) {
            agree.removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            agree.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
    //we convert the button into an anchor
    agree.click(function () {
        window.location = $(this).data("href") + "&cbrblaccpt=true";
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**: Because we are using a button instead of an anchor (`<a></a>`)

```
#accept {
    background: url(http://goo.gl/kCsKU3) center top no-repeat;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 44px;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#accept:disabled {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
#accept:active {
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

And finally, the **HTML**: Note we're using `data-href` attribute for the link instead of a simple `href`because this is a button, not an anchor anymore.

```
<input id="agreeCheckbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="agreeCheckbox">I agree to the terms</label>
<button data-href="link/?cbur=a" id="accept" disabled="disabled"></button>
```

### JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2zej2cg/

Comment: Hi Frondor. Thanks for taking the time to do that for me.

I just have a question though. Does my original script I posted come into it at all? I only ask because this is being used for a Clickbank upsell (basically an offer after someone makes an initial purchase), and in order to authorise the upsell purchase, Clickbank say...

"It is very important that you collect and pass the cbrblaccpt parameter to ClickBank if you are selling a recurring billing product.  You must collect acceptance to terms from the consumer to set this value or your flow will not be approved."

Comment: Are you talking about `&cbrblaccpt=true` part of the string? You can add it in the line where I say "we convert the button into an anchor". And instead of `window.location = $(this).data("href");` you can use ´window.location = $(this).data("href") + "&cbrblaccpt=true";´.
I've edited my answer and added this code. 
Hope this now work for you.

Comment: Hi Frondor. I really struggled to get it to work with the img button I wanted to use. In the end I found a TinyMCE plugin that allowed me to alter how it behaves so it doesn't strip onclick and onchange. Even so, thanks a lot for trying to help. I really appreciate your time. Cheers.