# How to Include "onclick" Object in WordPress HTML

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm using attempting to add an "onclick" object to a page in a singlesite (i.e. rather than multisite) WordPress that triggers an event.  The code is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="_speakpipe_open_widget(); return false;">Send a voice message</a>
```

When attempting to save the code, WordPress strips the onclick object leaving:

```
<a href="#">Send a voice message</a>
```

A user on another forum [suggested](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/2-administrator-users-visual-editor-strips-onclick-on-1-of-them) that this restriction should only apply to multisite non-superadmin users.  Again, this is a siglesite with only one admin user.

It is understood that WordPress removes "onclick" from HTML to prevent malicious code.  Still, does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an extra JS filter, but WordPress *used to* look at a whitelisted global array called `$allowedposttags` before filtering HTML. You could try creating a plugin, or adding code to your theme's functions.php file (if that still exists), to whitelist the `onclick` attribute of the anchor node.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that with current Wordpress (I'm on 4.9.4), TinyMCE does the filtering directly on the editor screen, not when the form is submitted. The allowedtags and allowedposttags don't seem to matter, so the solution above does not solve the problem for me.

The method I have developed uses the `tiny_mce_before_init` filter to alter the allowed tags within TinyMCE. The trick is to add the `extended_valid_elements` setting with the updated versions of the elements allowed for `a`.

First, look in the page http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:valid_elements to find the current value for `a`, which right now is

```
a[rel|rev|charset|hreflang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur]
```

And add to the end of that the `onclick` attribute:

```
a[rel|rev|charset|hreflang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur|onclick]
```

Then use that in the filter function like this:

```
function allow_button_onclick_mce($settings) {
  $settings['extended_valid_elements'] =  "a[rel|rev|charset|hreflang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|onfocus|onblur|onclick]";
  return $settings;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'allow_button_onclick_mce');
```

which you install in your `functions.php` file in Wordpress. You can see it in action by toggling the text and visual view on the edit page. Without the extended list, the onclick goes away. With it, it remains.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by changing the anchor tag into button and adding a script. For more info please refer to this link: [Wordpress TinyMCE Strips OnClick & OnChange (need jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753797/wordpress-tinymce-strips-onclick-onchange-need-jquery).

Comment: Thanks, @Anoop Asok.  Per comment below to Arty-chan, I'm checking with the theme producer and will update.

Answer (score 1):

By resolving, I'm assuming you mean to allow the onclick attribute. You will want to be careful with this, because modifying the allowed tags does this for all your users.

You can modify the list of allowed tags and attributes, by adding this to your functions.php file:

```
function allow_onclick_content() {
  global $allowedposttags, $allowedtags;
  $newattribute = "onclick";

  $allowedposttags["a"][$newattribute] = true;
  $allowedtags["a"][$newattribute] = true; //unnecessary?
}
add_action( 'init', 'allow_onclick_content' );
```

I suggest trying it with only $allowedposttags first to see if that works for you. According to this [other stackexchange post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17089/what-are-allowedposttags-and-allowedtags), you should only need allowedtags if you need it for comments or possibly non-logged-in users, but when I did something similar in the past, I needed both of them to work.

On a side note, if you want a list of all already allowed tags and attributes, look inside your [/wp-includes/kses.php file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L0).

Comment: Thanks, @Arty-chan.  I tried adding this to my custom-functions.php file at the parent- and child-themes (my theme producer strongly advises not to change the functions.php file so new versions don't overwrite changes).  The onclick content continues to get removed.  I'll check with the theme producer next to see if any resolution and will update.

Comment: Are you the creator/maintainer or the child theme? If so, there's no reason not to just use functions.php since in a child theme, it adds to the existing parent functions.php rather than override